# wso2elb services mapping not working with all configured hostnames

Tags: wso2

I'm currently deploying some wso2as cluster, and am facing a strange problem with URL mapping.
I have setup two worker nodes (named was0 and was1), a manager node (named mgt) and an ELB (named elb).

The installation seems working fine, as I'm able to call URL mapped on load balancer like the following : http://was0.domain/services/... , was0.domain being mapped on the load balancer IP on the station accessing this address (outside the cluster).
When I call services on this endpoint, I'm able to load balance as I can notice that my wsdl has enpoints based on was0 and was1. The two worker nodes are pretty detected as application nodes on the ELB.

The problem I encounter however is that when I use was0 based URL, it works fine, but when I try to use the was1 one, the load balancer returns a blank page, and I don't notice any error in logs. I have both hosts was1 and was0 defined in my cluster configuration as application members for AS.
If I try from the ELB node to access the was1 based webservice directly on the WAS, I'm able to access it without problem (so the service is working on was1 node, and this node is also detected and registered inside the cluster, but not accessible through cluster).
Finally, this results in one call working when round robin targets was0, and one call not working when targetting was1.

So I'm currently wondering if I understood well the cluster behavior: should it work for both application servers mapped URL, or is it normal to have only the first was0 responding with success? How could I force generated WSDL to return a valid endpoint URL?
What I understood by reading documentation is that I need mapping WAS URLs on the ELB, and that this one will then balance on all WAS servers, but it doesn't seem working like that.

Please tell me if you need some configuration part, diagram or example, I didn't paste it here because it's quite big :)

For information, I had the same problem when balancing through 2 wso2esb worker nodes, but was able to solve it by forcing WSDL URLs prefix by the first node URL (esb0) with the WSDLEPRPrefix in ESB configuration. As I don't have a such setting in wso2as, I don't know how accessing the URL returned in WSDL.

Thank you by advance for your help,

BOUCNIAUX Benjamin

Comment: I found the solution, if someone has the same problem one day, here is the way to solve it:

AS axis2 cluster configurations must be based on real servernames (was0, was1), whereas carbon.xml must define Hostname to the mapped URL, which will be shared between all WAS.

In my case, having two nodes was0.domain and was1.domain, the solution is to use some URL based on was.domain (without identifying physical server), and define carbon.xml hostname to was.domain on the AS nodes.

Comment: Load balancer will then detect that these two servers handles was.domain, and will dispatch requests to them.

On ELB side, I had also to define the hosts entries for the AS domain to be was.domain instead of having two hosts was0 and was1.

I hope this will help someone one day :)

Comment: Can you answer this question and mark it as resolved?